# generar variables DATA dinamicas con VUE

Tags: vue.js

Estoy tratando de definir variables dinamicas para `VUE`, para luego usarlas en `v-for`. al cargar la pagina funcionan, pero si luego cambio sus valores, ya no cambian los valores en la vista.

`VUE`

```
const app = new Vue({
        el: '#mainCreate',
        data: {
            modules : [],
            feature: []
        },
    });
```

Esta función la estoy usando para generar las variables dentro de `feature`:

```
 /*crea dinamicamente los feautres en module*/
    function creatDataFeatures (){
        $.each(app.modules, function(index,module){
            app.feature[index] = module.features;
        });
    }
```

Así la estoy cargando en la vista:

```
<!-- caracteristicas-->
<table class="table table-striped mt-3">
   <tbody>
      <tr v-for="feat in feature[index]">
           <td>
              <input type="checkbox" checked>
          </td>
           <td>
              @{{feat.title}}
           </td>
           <td class="text-info">
              @{{feat.price ? '$ '+feat.price : '$ 0'}}
           </td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
```

Al cargar la pagina me carga los datos correctamente, pero si luego cambio los valores ejm: `feature[index] = [other array]` (lo cambio por el mismo formato de datos que los del inicio) en la vista no cambia nada. una solución o una alternativa estarían genial.

Comment: Estaria bueno saber como armas el otro array. ya que estas tomando variables con nombre, en el array deberian tener los mismos nombres.

Answer (score 3):

Solucionado

La linea `app.feature[index] = module.features;` cae en la limitación de Vue con respecto a las matrices.

Se soluciona usando `VUE.SET` ver: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats

```js
    $.each(app.modules, function(index,module){
        Vue.set(app.feature, index, module.features); // changed this line
    });
```

> Debido a las limitaciones en JavaScript, Vue no puede detectar los siguientes cambios en una matriz:

> 1.Cuando establece directamente un elemento con el índice, por ejemplo  `vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue`

> 2.Cuando se modifica el tamaño del array, ejm. `vm.items.length = newLength`
>
> Para superar la advertencia 1, ambos de los siguientes harán lo mismo que  `vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue`, pero también activarán las actualizaciones de estado en el sistema de reactividad:
>
> ```
> // Vue.set
> Vue.set(vm.items, indexOfItem, newValue)
> ```